# How to write data to a slice of structs

Tags: go, struct, slice

First, the raw input data:

```
CPF                PRIVATE     INCOMPLETO  DATA DA ÚLTIMA COMPRA TICKET MÉDIO          TICKET DA ÚLTIMA COMPRA LOJA MAIS FREQUÊNTE LOJA DA ÚLTIMA COMPRA
041.091.641-25     0           0           NULL                  NULL                  NULL                    NULL                NULL
058.189.421-98     0           0           NULL                  NULL                  NULL                    NULL                NULL
769.013.439-49     0           0           NULL                  NULL                  NULL                    NULL                NULL
```

I have this struct:

```
type row struct {
    cpf                 string
    private             bool
    incompleto          bool
    ultCompra           string
    ticketMedio         float64
    ticketUltimo        float64
    lojaMaisFreq        string
    lojaUltCompra       string
}
```

I created a slice of it:

```
var parsedData []row
```

And i want to write data in a for range loop. The data comes from a txt and i parsed it.

I did a for range loop with with strings.Field like this:

```
for i1, v1 := range data {
    // ignore the first line because it is the header
    if i1 == 0 {
        continue
    }

    lines := strings.Fields(v1)
```

The data is now a [][]string like this:

```
[004.350.709-32 0 0 2013-05-27 599,60 599,60 79.379.491/0008-50 79.379.491/0008-50]
[152.110.128-01 0 0 2013-05-27 449,90 449,90 79.379.491/0008-50 79.379.491/0008-50]
[067.737.339-28 0 0 2013-05-27 299,90 299,90 79.379.491/0008-50 79.379.491/0008-50]
```

So i iterate over it in a for range loop:

```
for i2, v2 := range data {
    fmt.Println(i2, "-", v2)
}
```

Which gives me this:

```
0 - 004.350.709-32
1 - 0
2 - 0
3 - 2013-05-27
4 - 599,60
5 - 599,60
6 - 79.379.491/0008-50
7 - 79.379.491/0008-50
```

After this i created functions to treat all the data to be compatible with each field in the struct.

Now... How do i put everything into the slice of structs? Here is what i'm doing:

```
// using the index of the first loop
newIndex := i1 - 1 // since it ignores 0 which is the header
switch i2 {
                case 0:
                    parsedData[newIndex].cpf = cleanStrings(v2)
                case 1:
                    parsedData[newIndex].private = strToBool(v2)
                case 2:
                    parsedData[newIndex].incompleto = strToBool(v2)
                case 3:
                    parsedData[newIndex].ultCompra = v2
                case 4:
                    parsedData[newIndex].ticketMedio = strToFloat(v2)
                case 5:
                    parsedData[newIndex].ticketUltimo = strToFloat(v2)
                case 6:
                    parsedData[newIndex].lojaMaisFreq = cleanStrings(v2)
                case 7:
                    parsedData[newIndex].lojaUltCompra = cleanStrings(v2)
            }
```

But this is wrong. It gives me index out of range. Since it is an empty slice I probably have to append to it instead, but i can't wrap my head around how to do this.

I have to create a new row struct for every loop?

Comment: Please provide an example of the input data

Comment: Edited. It's on top.

Answer (score 1):

So, i just figured out. I got the number of lines of the txt file with len and made the slice:

```
parsedData := make([]row, len(data)-1)

for i1, v1 := range data {
    if i1 == 0 {
        continue
    }
    lines := strings.Fields(v1)
    for i2, v2 := range lines {
        newIndex := i1 - 1
        switch i2 {
        case 0:
            parsedData[newIndex].cpf = cleanStrings(v2)
        case 1:
            parsedData[newIndex].private = strToBool(v2)
        case 2:
            parsedData[newIndex].incompleto = strToBool(v2)
        case 3:
            parsedData[newIndex].ultCompra = v2
        case 4:
            parsedData[newIndex].ticketMedio = strToFloat(v2)
        case 5:
            parsedData[newIndex].ticketUltimo = strToFloat(v2)
        case 6:
            parsedData[newIndex].lojaMaisFreq = cleanStrings(v2)
        case 7:
            parsedData[newIndex].lojaUltCompra = cleanStrings(v2)
        }
    }
}

return parsedData
```

And now everything works!